# Fetch ids for two consecutive rows whose column has same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySql table with following values.

```
id   model  category    Code    item_type
--------------------------------------
543   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     0
535   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     1
532   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     0
528   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     0
524   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     1
518   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     0
515   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     1
510   XYZ     PQR       ABC12     0
508   XYZ     PQR       QRP24     0
495   XYZ     PQR       QRP24     0
--    --      --          --      --
```

**Example schema and data**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_tpe` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=544 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (495,'XYZ','PQR','QRP24',0);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (508,'XYZ','PQR','QRP24',0);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (510,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',0);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (515,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',1);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (518,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',0);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (524,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',1);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (528,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',0);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (532,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',0);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (535,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',1);
insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`model`,`category`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values (543,'XYZ','PQR','ABC12',0);
```

**Problem**

Requirement is that I need to fetch `ids` for those two records whose `item_type` is 0 and these rows must be consecutive, provided that they share a same `Code`.

So for example,
in above table, the required ids are `532 and 528`, `508 and 495` and so on , there could be many.

**Update**

Sample output for above table should be an array

```
[532,528] if `code='ABC12'` and `[508, 495]` if the `code='QRP24'`
```

**Update 2**
The desired output should be fetched when the `code` value is given

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by "consecutive"? what ordering do you have, ID DESC ?

Comment: Can you please post sample output as well ?

Comment: @2oppin, ID is in descending order, `consecutive`, here by I mean two rows that comes one after another which has `item_type=0` and they have same Column value for `Code`

Comment: @JigneshPatel, Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables to keep track of your previous row. It's not pretty in MySQL but this works:

```
SELECT id, lastid, code FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        code,
        item_tpe,
        @last_id as lastid,
        @last_code as lastcode,
        @last_item_tpe as lastitemtpe,
        @last_id:=id,
        @last_code:=code,
        @last_item_tpe:=item_tpe
    FROM
        test_table,
        ( select
            @last_id := 0,
            @last_code := "",
            @last_item_tpe:=0
        ) SQLVars
    ORDER BY code, id
) a
WHERE
    a.code = a.lastcode
    AND a.item_tpe = 0
    AND a.lastitemtpe = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work properly, it doesn't fetch all the valid rows

Comment: Can you give me an example where it doesn't work? For the test data you provided it returns the two expected pairs.

Comment: Hey, here is a link to test data, have uploaded it to mediafire - http://www.mediafire.com/file/xv6yme6fswvybqu/testdata.sql

Comment: Thanks, but please give me a small set where my code does not work

Comment: Like, the output should contain ids `30638360,30633253` as well. Moreover there are 10000 rows and the result is only 6 rows.

Comment: 30638360 and 30633253 are not consecutive, so they should not be in the result

Comment: Oh! my mistake, i didn't explained properly. If we consider query `SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE `code`='356173064465888'`, then those two ids comes consecutively. So may be I need to edit my question. the `code` must be given in order to get desired result. Please view my question update

Comment: In that case just add `ORDER BY code, id` to the inner query. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Seems working fine! will do more check and will eventually accept your answer. Thanks Buddy!

Comment: Re change to `ORDER BY code, id` - that is useful IF want to include duplicates REGARDLESS of their ids. As per OP, IF ONLY WANT CONSECUTIVE rows (when excluding non-matching rows), correct answer is `ORDER BY id WHERE item_type=0`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. Here's one:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_tpe` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=544 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert  into `test_table`(`id`,`code`,`item_tpe`) values 
(495,'QRP24',0),
(508,'QRP24',0),
(510,'ABC12',0),
(515,'ABC12',1),
(518,'ABC12',0),
(524,'ABC12',1),
(528,'ABC12',0),
(532,'ABC12',0),
(535,'ABC12',1),
(543,'ABC12',0);

SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) next 
         FROM test_table x 
         JOIN test_table y 
           ON y.id > x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) a 
  JOIN test_table b 
    ON b.id = a.next 
   AND b.code = a.code 
   AND b.item_tpe = a.item_tpe 
 WHERE a.item_tpe = 0;
+-----+-------+----------+------+
| id  | code  | item_tpe | next |
+-----+-------+----------+------+
| 495 | QRP24 |        0 |  508 |
| 528 | ABC12 |        0 |  532 |
+-----+-------+----------+------+
```

Something along these lines could also work...

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev_code = x.code THEN 
         CASE WHEN @prev_item_tpe = item_tpe THEN @status:='true'ELSE @status:='false' END
          ELSE @status := 'false'END status
     , @prev_code := x.code
     , @prev_item_tpe := x.item_tpe
  FROM test_table x
     , (SELECT @prev_code := null, @prev_item_tpe := null, @status := null) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY x.id
) a
WHERE status = 'true' AND item_tpe = 0;
```

Edit: A quick test on your enlarged data set reveals that both queries return the same rows...

```
SELECT a.id     
     , a.item_tpe 
     , a.code       
     , a.next   
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) next
         FROM test_table x
         JOIN test_table y
           ON y.id > x.id
        GROUP
           BY x.id
     ) a
  JOIN test_table b
    ON b.id = a.next
   AND b.code = a.code
   AND b.item_tpe = a.item_tpe
 WHERE a.item_tpe = 0;
+--------+----------+------------+--------+
| id     | item_tpe | code       | next   |
+--------+----------+------------+--------+
| 491209 |        0 | 3066754917 | 491210 |
| 491210 |        0 | 3066754917 | 491211 |
| 491211 |        0 | 3066754917 | 491212 |
+--------+----------+------------+--------+

SELECT a.id     
     , a.item_tpe 
     , a.code       
     , a.status
  FROM
(
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev_code = x.code THEN
         CASE WHEN @prev_item_tpe = item_tpe THEN @status:='true'ELSE @status:='false' END
          ELSE @status := 'false'END status
     , @prev_code := x.code
     , @prev_item_tpe := x.item_tpe
  FROM test_table x
     , (SELECT @prev_code := null, @prev_item_tpe := null, @status := null) vars
 ORDER
    BY x.id
) a
WHERE status = 'true' AND item_tpe = 0;
+--------+----------+------------+--------+
| id     | item_tpe | code       | status |
+--------+----------+------------+--------+
| 491210 |        0 | 3066754917 | true   |
| 491211 |        0 | 3066754917 | true   |
| 491212 |        0 | 3066754917 | true   |
+--------+----------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks, The first solution works if there are fewer data, but for large table it the query took forever to execute. And the second solution just retrieves one id, another associated id is not retrieved, like in case `next` in first solution

Comment: I would have thought that an index on (code,type) would be pretty quick.

Comment: It even is much slower when there are only 10000 rows in the table

Comment: The second query returns all rows.

Comment: No second query doesn't return all the records, in 10000 rows it only returns 6 rows. Moreover second query doesnot return `next` id like it does in first query

Comment: Can you provide a data set that demonstrates the failure.

Comment: I have uploaded it to mediafire http://www.mediafire.com/file/xv6yme6fswvybqu/testdata.sql

For example `30638360,30633253` these two ids should also be in output, but it doesn't

Comment: Hi one little mistake in my question, please check the updates and the bottom of my original post

Comment: I've tested my queries on your data set. They both return the same result.